# Run garbage collector

Tags: lua

I have a number of Lua scripts running in mac Mac OS application along with Objective C code. The memory footprint of my application continues to rise over time. Therefore, I decided to call `collectgarbage` function periodically from my Lua script. Since, I am new to Lua, I am not sure if I should call it in every script or calling it from any of the script is fine i.e. does it collect the garbage from all open Lua states or just from the states associated with the current Lua file?

Comment: You should not call `collectgarbage` yourself. In the vast majority of cases, Lua knows just fine when to collect garbage. For those rare cases where you need to influence the amount of garbage collection cycles, you can [adjust the runtime parameters](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.5) of the garbage collector. Manually forcing a garbage collector run is only reasonable in very rare circumstances and you should avoid doing so if possible.

Comment: @ComicSansMS, that comment could be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory, like everything in Lua, is per-Lua state. Different Lua states are *completely* separate, and there is no (direct) way for anything done in one Lua state to affect the contents of another.

Also, Lua doesn't really know what a "script" is. Or a file. There's just the code the interpreter happens to be currently executing. It certainly does not keep track of memory on a per-"script" basis.

`collectgarbage` therefore works on the level that it can: it collects garbage from the current Lua state.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to all of your Lua states, you can use the `lua_close` function which collects all garbage from the Lua state that you pass to it as an argument.

```
void lua_close (lua_State *L);
```

This, however, frees all objects in the Lua state.

The other more reasonable alternative from the C API is the `lua_gc` method.

```
int lua_gc (lua_State *L, int what);
```

Either way you'll need to pass it a state, and the garbage collector will only clear the dynamic memory used by that specific state.

For more information, look up `lua_close` and `lua_gc` in the manual:

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html